# how should i define session_start(); with include files correctly?

Tags: php

how should i define `session_start();` with include files correctly? because i made a `session_start();` at `login_proses.php` and i wanna include `koneksi.php`

but apparently found an error
it says that the files cannot found

here is the error warning

> Warning: include(koneksi.php): failed to open stream: No such file or
> directory in C:\xampp2\htdocs\spk\admin\login_proses.php on line 3
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening 'koneksi.php' for inclusion
> (include_path='C:\xampp2\php\PEAR') in
> C:\xampp2\htdocs\spk\admin\login_proses.php on line 3
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_query()
> in C:\xampp2\htdocs\spk\admin\login_proses.php:8 Stack trace: #0
> {main} thrown in C:\xampp2\htdocs\spk\admin\login_proses.php on line 8

to make it more clear here is the screenshot

[this is login_proses.php file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0vim.png)

[this is koneksi.php file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKe4N.png)

i saved login_proses at -> htdocs/spk/admin/login_proses.php
i saved koneksi.php at -> htdocs/spk/koneksi.php

i used localhost/ to run my program

i hope anyone could help me
thank you

Comment: login_proses.php and koneksi.php is in different directory

Comment: Why are you asking about session_start, when that has absolutely _nothing_ to do with your actual issue?

Comment: **Warning:** `mysql_*` extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Instead, either the [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extension should be used. See also the [MySQL API Overview](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

Answer (score 0):

since the koneksi.php is one step back you should do this in your login_proces.php
change `include "koneksi.php";` to `include "../koneksi.php";`

Comment: Whoever down voted this answer step out and care to explain why you down voted in the comment.